# Sublime3 why does it circle the letter "s"?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm new to sublime, sure this is a simple issue. It's circling the letter "s" and i'm not sure why, these are my settings.

```
{
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Colorsublime - Themes/CarbonightBlue.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 10,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1,
    "theme": "SoDaReloaded Dark.sublime-theme"
}
```

installed packages are:
BracketHighlighter
ColorSublime
Emmett
Sidebar

any help would be appreciated, google hasn't helped much.

Comment: What letter s is it circling? One letter s? Every letter s? Is this in a particular file you are editing? Any file you are editing? What file format have you picked (with the menu in the lower right of the window)?

Comment: its circling every letter s in red only on .html files, sorry SO won't let me post images yet i just joined, so i posted it as my profile pic. :)

Comment: do you have the find panel open by any chance?

Comment: that did the trick...thank you sir